# SQL Server slow after restore on better server

Tags: sql-server, performance, restore

We had a SQL Server 2014 Express database on server A. After we back up the database and restore it to a better server B, and use SQL Server 2017 Express, we found that queries take longer to execute.

These are the tasks I have completed after the restore:

- Rebuild Indexes
- Reorganize All
- Update Statistics

but I still have almost 5- 6 seconds slower results.

I am not a SQL Server DBA, so I would like to ask if SQL auto optimize queries  plans and the only thing left is just  to wait a few days to workout by itself?

Or is there anything left to check?

Comment: Maybe its a best practice to see your index again, make sure have you set clustered index correctly? And make sure that you got your non clustered index as needed for good efficiency, because too much non-clustered could also lead to slow performance, and maybe you could consider using covering index instead non clustered index, which one is better to be implemented into each column.

Comment: compare execution plans between the two?   SET STATISTICS IO and run some sample queries on both, see if there is a difference

Comment: The bottom line, how your columns are indexed. And how are read and write data being processed with the index setting. Would that promote effectivity? Or just some more interruptions of the processed data pointing to many indexes.

Comment: "5-6 seconds" doesn't tell much. How long does the query take to run on both machines? What is the server configuration? Are they cloud instances? Could it be that machine B has noisy neighbors and A hasn't? There are a lot of factors that could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

You mix it up. Ok, first - how is the server better?

But generally betwen 2014 and 2017 the query optimizer was changed and will not get more probleamtic with bad indices. Not statistics only - but it will rely more on indices. Check your indices, check what queries are slow, look at the query pans.

Ths is NOT administration - this is "programmer error showing up in 2ß17 while 2014 could work around it".

Also possibly try starting the servcie with trace flag 8491 (disable new cardinality estimate) and see whether the behavior is similar. You now also may have a paramter sniffing problem (trace lag 4136)